# "RuntimeError: self must be a matrix"

Tags: python, pytorch, rbm

**RBM**
we add methods to convert the visible input to the hidden representation and the hidden representation back to reconstructed visible input. Both methods return the activation probabilities, while the sample_h method also returns the observed hidden state as well

```
<pre><code>
    class RBM():
        def __init__(self, visible_dim, hidden_dim, gaussian_hidden_distribution=False):
            self.visible_dim = visible_dim
            self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
            self.gaussian_hidden_distribution = gaussian_hidden_distribution
            # intialize parameters
            self.W = torch.randn(visible_dim, hidden_dim) * 0.1
            self.h_bias = torch.zeros(hidden_dim)   # visible --> hidden
            self.v_bias = torch.zeros(visible_dim)  # hidden --> visible
            # parameters for learning with momentum
            self.W_momentum = torch.zeros(visible_dim, hidden_dim)
            self.h_bias_momentum = torch.zeros(hidden_dim)
            self.v_bias_momentum = torch.zeros(visible_dim)
       
        def sample_h(self, v):
            activation = torch.mm(v, self.W) + self.h_bias
            if self.gaussian_hidden_distribution:
                return activation, torch.normal(activation, torch.tensor([1]))
            else:
                p = torch.sigmoid(activation)
                return p, torch.bernoulli(p)
    
        def sample_v(self, h):
            """Get visible activation probabilities"""
            activation = torch.mm(h, self.W.t()) + self.v_bias
            p = torch.sigmoid(activation)
            return p
        def update_weights(self, v0, vk, ph0, phk, lr, 
                           momentum_coef, weight_decay, batch_size):
            self.W_momentum *= momentum_coef
            self.W_momentum += torch.mm(v0.t(), ph0) - torch.mm(vk.t(), phk)
            self.h_bias_momentum *= momentum_coef
            self.h_bias_momentum += torch.sum((ph0 - phk), 0)
            self.v_bias_momentum *= momentum_coef
            self.v_bias_momentum += torch.sum((v0 - vk), 0)
            self.W += lr*self.W_momentum/batch_size
            self.h_bias += lr*self.h_bias_momentum/batch_size
            self.v_bias += lr*self.v_bias_momentum/batch_size
            self.W -= self.W * weight_decay # L2 weight decay
</code></pre>
```

**Training RBM**
While training the model i am getting " RuntimeError: self must be a matrix", can someone help me out and tell me what changes should I make in code.

```
<pre><code>
     models = [] # store trained RBM models
        visible_dim = 784
        rbm_train_dl = train_dl_flat
        for hidden_dim in [1000, 500, 250, 2]:
            # configs - we have a different configuration for the last layer
            num_epochs = 30 if hidden_dim == 2 else 10
            lr = 1e-3 if hidden_dim == 2 else 0.1
            use_gaussian = hidden_dim == 2
            
            # train RBM
            rbm = RBM(visible_dim=visible_dim, hidden_dim=hidden_dim, 
                      gaussian_hidden_distribution=use_gaussian)
            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                for i, data_list in enumerate(train_dl):
                    v0 = data_list[0]
                    
                    # get reconstructed input via Gibbs sampling with k=1
                    _, hk = rbm.sample_h(v0)
                    pvk = rbm.sample_v(hk)
                    # update weights
                    rbm.update_weights(v0, pvk, rbm.sample_h(v0)[0], rbm.sample_h(pvk)[0], lr, 
                                       momentum_coef=0.5 if epoch < 5 else 0.9, 
                                       weight_decay=2e-4, 
                                       batch_size=sample_data.shape[0])
            models.append(rbm)
            # rederive new data loader based on hidden activations of trained model
            new_data = [model.sample_h(data_list[0])[0].detach().numpy() for data_list in rbm_train_dl]
            rbm_train_dl = DataLoader(
                TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(np.concatenate(new_data))), 
                batch_size=64, shuffle=False
            )
            visible_dim = hidden_dim
</code></pre>
```

**ERROR**

```
<pre><code>

    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-53fe4223334d> in <module>()
         16 
         17             # get reconstructed input via Gibbs sampling with k=1
    ---> 18             _, hk = rbm.sample_h(v0)
         19             pvk = rbm.sample_v(hk)
         20             # update weights
    
    <ipython-input-1-49d2abc1da92> in sample_h(self, v)
         15     def sample_h(self, v):
         16         """Get sample hidden values and activation probabilities"""
    ---> 17         activation = torch.mm(v, self.W) + self.h_bias
         18         if self.gaussian_hidden_distribution:
         19             return activation, torch.normal(activation, torch.tensor([1]))
    
    RuntimeError: self must be a matrix
</code></pre>
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you can only call the method ```sample_h``` on a  matrix. You call it on an instance of RBM, but RBM is not a matrix nor inherits from matrix. In other words, you're using a method on an object that doesn't have that method, so there's no reason to expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need **broadcasting** (because you're multiplying 1d vector on 2D matrix).

Try using `torch.matmul` instead.

This link for understanding the difference between `mm` and `matmul`:
[What's the difference between torch.mm, torch.matmul and torch.mul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924697/whats-the-difference-between-torch-mm-torch-matmul-and-torch-mul)